# OO Inheritance with different forms

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to grasp something. The whole inheritance thing within OO.

In my WordPress environment I created a custom `meta_box` the OO way.

A function called `display()` loads the content of the metabox.
I want to load different contents in the meta box depending on what the user selects. My idea is to do this with inheritance. So the `display()` loads nothing in the parent class but when I extend it to a child class containing it's own content I can call that.

Is this even remotely how I should approach inheritance?

So basically:

```
class CMB{

public function init(){
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add' ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save' ) );
}   
/**
* Adds a meta box to the post editing screen
*/  
public function add(){

}

/**
* Render Meta Box content.
*/
public function display() {
// This stays empty for the parent class.
}

/**
* Save the meta when the post is saved.
*/
public function save( $post_id){


    }
}   
class newForm extends CMB{
    public function newForm(){
    // content of form goes here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well It is Strategy Pattern. You should make parent class Abstract. So no one can create instance of that. Also you can force childs to implements some methods(by abstract keyword). Final keyword means that child can't modify that method

```
abstract class CMB{

    final public function init(){
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save' ) );
    }
    /**
     * Adds a meta box to the post editing screen
     */
    abstract public function add();

    /**
     * Render Meta Box content.
     */
    abstract public function display();

    /**
     * Save the meta when the post is saved.
     */
    public function save($post_id){
         /* SAVING STAFF */
         /* change to final public function save if want from that method to be same in each child */
    }
}
class newForm extends CMB{
    public function display(){
        // content of form goes here.
    }
    public function add(){

    }
    public function save($post_id){

    }
}
```

A nice quote from php.net manual comments:
*On the other hand, an Abstract Class is like a partially built class. It is much like a document with blanks to fill in. It might be using English, but that isn't as important as the fact that some of the document is already written.* ~ ironiridis

Comment: I like the way you think. Had to read up about `abstract` but yeah this seems to be it.

Comment: Okay this is working perfect. However I'm about to create multiple instances of this class. Is it wise to constantly duplicate the save function? Wouldn't it be possible to not `abstract`  the save function